# How to disable xfce's pop up notifications upon boot?

Tags: kali-linux, xfce

Below is the notifications that xfce show me upon boot in Kali. To close these windows every time I start is annoying. Is there a way to disable them?
[image]

Comment: Um, these are **not** notifications, these are the about windows of certain apps. Must be the wrong screenshot?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I meant. Back to the question, is there a way to disable them?

Comment: This looks like a prank. Maybe your own. No way you could even show these windows without launching the said applications and invoking Help -> About which takes quite a lot of mouse clicks.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you man. I upgraded my Kali a couple days ago and this was apparently one of the things that its installed. I'd like to remove the entire suite but I'm afraid I'd mess something's up.